# SMPlayer + mpv missing OSD

Tags: video-player, smplayer

The OSD shows nothing when I change the sound volume or jump. It used to show "Volume: XXX%" and current time with a bar. Changed after some update. How can I have it back?

SMPlayer 17.8.0-1~xenial1
ppa:rvm/smplayer

mpv 2:0.26.0+git3~xenial
ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On "SMPlayer -> Preferences -> Advanced -> MPlayer/mpv -> Options" add "--osd-level=1".

For details about the problem and the solution follow the link:
http://forum.smplayer.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8893